# How does Array#- (subtract operator) compare elements for equality?

Tags: ruby, arrays, operator-overloading, subtraction, comparison-operators

When I call `Array#-` it doesn't seems to call any comparison method on the strings I'm comparing:

```
class String
  def <=>(v)
    puts "#{self} <=> #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def ==(v)
    puts "#{self} == #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def =~(v)
    puts "#{self} =~ #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def ===(v)
    puts "#{self} == #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def eql?(v)
    puts "#{self}.eql? #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def equal?(v)
    puts "#{self}.equal? #{v}"
    super(v)
  end

  def hash()
    puts "#{self}.hash"
    super
  end
end

p %w{one two three} - %w{two}
```

It just returns:

```
["one", "three"]
```

So, what is `Array#-` doing?

Also, I'm using Ruby 1.9.2p290. In 1.8.7 it seems to cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Try invoking it with `irb` (!). After reading your class definition it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: @JoshLee What do you mean it enters an infinite loop? When I execute the script it exits without any problem

Comment: It prints out


N == N
N == m
m == m
N == n
m == n
M == n
l == n

over and over…

Comment: Interesting question. `['one', 'two', 'three'].delete('two')` uses `==`. You forgot `equal?`, but it's not the searched one.

Comment: @JoshLee not in my computer at least, I'm using ruby 1.9.2p290

Comment: @knut Oh it wasn't listed in http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html is it an alias of .eql? ?

Comment: It`s defined in BasicObject (and BasicObject is a ancestor of String). So it is inherited. More details in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7156955/whats-the-difference-between-equal-eql-and

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529873/how-does-rubys-array-compare-elements-for-equality - But you already tested String#hash.

Comment: String#hash has no parameter. I edited your question - please wait for review.

Comment: You'd use `Array.foo` to indicate a method called on the `Array` class itself, whereas you'd use `Array#foo` to indicate a method called on an instance of `Array`.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm You are right, I forgot, sorry, thanks for correcting it ñ.ñ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[source code for `Array#-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

It appears that rather than testing for equality, a hash is made from the second array. Anything not contained in that array is pushed into the resultant array.

Array difference in 1.8.7 is implemented this way also. The changes to String only cause problems in irb (not in a plain ruby script).

Comment: @lucapette: ah ok, probably any repl will have issues.

Comment: But if it's not testing for equality how does it knows if something is contained in the array? I mean, it have to test for equality at some point right? :|

Comment: @Zequez: no, it just needs to hash the string (see `"foo".hash`).  The hash lookup is how it determines if an item is contained in the array.

Comment: @cam Ohhhhhh I got it now, so, no case insensitive array subtraction this way then haha. Thanks a lot for clearing it out! ñ.ñ Though it's still weird that it does not call the hash method in the string =/

Comment: So if it's hashing the string, why isn't `hash` getting called on `String`?